# How do I implement this max file size script with my HTML?

Tags: javascript, upload

I have been given this JavaScript script to restrict max file size before it is uploaded, but I'm not sure how I would implement it with my current code.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   console.log(f.size);        /*<--Here is your size of the file! :D*/
  }
}

 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<label>Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" name="image" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
```

MODIFIED CODE:

```
  <p><label>Upload Image</label>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var max_size = 5120; // Max file size

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    // console.log(f.size);
     if(f.size > max_size) { // Check if file size is larger than max_size
     alert("Sorry, but the file that you selected is too large. Please upload a file that is no larger than " + max_size + " KB.");
      return false;
    } // end if
   } // end for loop
 } //  end function

 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
 </script>

                <input type="file" name="image" id="files"/><br />
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
            </p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </form>
```

Comment: The method isn't really complete, it's using a `console.log` debug thing.  Presumably you'd return false via the `onsubmit` event on the form if the comparison on `f.size` was greater than some threshold value you've predetermined.  You should still check on backend if the size is too large due to end users disabling javascript or doing some other magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `id` attribute to the file input, since the script is looking for an element with an `id` of *files*:

```
<label>Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="files" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120" />
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />​</p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RnuT8/

By the way, be aware that this JavaScript can be easily bypassed by simply disabling JavaScript or directly uploading the file to the server without using your form. I recommend that you check the file size with your server side PHP upload script as well.

## Modified Code

I have modified your script so you can enter a max size value and the script will check if it is greater than `max_size` or not:

```
window.onload = function() {

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
      var max_size = 5120; // Max file size
    
      // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
      var output = [];
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
       // console.log(f.size);
        if(f.size > max_size) { // Check if file size is larger than max_size
          alert("Sorry, but the file that you selected is too large. Please upload a file that is no larger than " + max_size + " KB.");
          return false;
        } // end if
      } // end for loop
    } //  end function

   document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}
```

But remember, this is *passable* and the file size should be validated on the server as well (the JavaScript is good too and speeds up stuff, but if you want security you *must* validate it on the server as well).

Comment: Note that you will also need to validate file_size on server side.

Comment: @Nathan thankyou for your reply, i still can't get the validation to work before the file begins to upload, any ideas?

Comment: @neeko I have edited my answer. Let me know if it works for you and if it does, please remember to click the check mark next to my answer to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/166675) :)

Comment: thankyou! i still can't seem to get it work my upload form looks like the one you posted and i copied the javascript, any ideas?

Comment: @neeko You put the modified script above in `<script></script>` tags, right?

Comment: thankyou, now it is displaying the pop up box but it is displaying no matter what size file, even if i increase the max file size limit

Comment: no sorry ignore that it is working thankyou so much!! any way to make it so that it doesnt select the file if it is too big

Comment: @neeko Glad it is working. :) And I'm not sure that you can do that since the JS can only check once the user selects the file.

Comment: thankyou, and one more quick question, any way to check the image resolution as well as file size?

Answer (score 1):

The script is looking for an element with an id of "files". Try adding the id on your input, like this:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="image" />
```